# What are examples of reducible elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

what is reducible elements ? what are the example of reducible element ?

whenever i  searched what is reducible elements ? in Google

It always  show  irreducible definition,

I know that if $p= ab$ implies either $a$ or $b$ is a  units  :$ a , b \in R$
then $p$ is called irreducible  element

For example : $1+ i$ is  an irreducible element in $\mathbb{Z[i]}$

why it is irreducible  because  take conjugate  of $1+i$  then  $( 1+i)(1-i)= 2$

Now we can write  $2 = (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

if $a^2+b^2 = 1$ then $(a+ib) (a-ib) =1 $ implies $a+ib $ is a  unit

Comment: $p$ is a reducible element, if $p$ is not irreducible. For example $6\in\mathbb{Z}$   is reducible since $6=2\cdot 3$ and neither $2$ nor $3$ is a unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$0$ and invertible elements are irrelevant here. We only consider elements in $R\setminus(\{0\}\cup R^{\times})$. Such an element $x$ is called reducible if there are **non-invertible** elements $a,b\in R$ such that $x=ab$.

For example, $10$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ since $10=2\times 5$.

$2$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ since $2=(1+i)(1-i)$.

If $F$ is a field and a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ of degree at least $2$ has a root $\alpha\in F$ then $f$ is reducible in $F[x]$ since $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$. (and $g$ is not invertible since its degree is $\deg(f)-1\geq 1$).

Comment: thanks a lots  @marks  now  i understand

Comment: @DietrichBurde   sorrry  Typo mistake i